# Elasticsearch yml file in tomcat7 failed to load settings

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, tomcat7

I`m using Spring MVC project in which I`m using elasticsearch. I have created an elasticsearch.yml file in my SRC project folder. However, when I`m running on tomcat7 server Im getting an error:

```
Failed to load setting from [file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/projectName/WEB-INF/classes/elasticsearch.yml]
```

These are contents in my elasticsearch.yml file

```
DATA_DIR=/var/data/elasticsearch/
```

Comment: have you integrated elasticsearch in tomcat? what is the reason that you have added your yml file in SRC directory?

Comment: @KumarKailash I want to keep my Data_DIR outside the tomcat. Before it was pointing to this directory (/var/lib/tomcat7/elasticsearch)

Comment: @KumarKailash funny thing is if I remove the .yml file from src directory, everything works

Comment: Yes you are rite. The elasticsearch.yml file would by default be loaded by the elasticsearch service from /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml , so i would suggest you load the configuration from this locaiton.

Comment: @KumarKailash how do I configure remote server to hold the data, elasticsearch running on another VM that does only search for me

Comment: @KumarKailash This is the scenario Im having.. I have installed elasticsearch on my ubuntu VM and tomcat7, Ive used elasticsearch maven in my project that is running on tomcat7. Now, on load it gives me an error "Failed to obtain a node lock, is the following location writable? [/var/lib/tomcat7/data/elasticsearch]. I know what is this mean? I want to point my data directory to another location by defining elasticsearch.yml file in SRC directory in my project but gives an error "Failed to load setting.. filename"

Comment: why don't you carry out a different approach. I suppose you could start elasticsearch as a service in ubuntu VM. In the default yml(in elasticsearch directory) make data_dir to point the a location which has permission to write. For your application configured through maven, try using TransportClient to make connection to elasticsearch in the same machine through ip address.